# Angular registration via jwt or error InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: angular

registration:

```
  public signUp(name: string, password: string): Observable<IEmployee> {
    return this.http.post<IEmployee>(`${environment.apiUrl}/sign_up.json`, {name, password });
  }
```

sign-up component:

```
this.formRegistration = this.builder.group({
  password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  phoneNumber: [null, Validators.required]
})

   public onRegistration() {
const { name, password } = this.formRegistration.value;
this.store.dispatch(new SignUp(name, password ));
  }
```

auth.actions:

```
    export class SignUp {
  public static readonly type = '[Auth] SignUp';
  constructor(public readonly name: string, public readonly password: string) {}
}

export class SignUpSuccess {
  public static readonly type = '[Auth] SignUpSuccess';
  constructor(public readonly employee: IEmployee) {}
}
```

And i got error with `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`. Im new with angular, what i need to do? (i think, need send jwt, but how?)

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you sure that the `sign_up.json` is exposed and not protected by authentication?

Comment: @Shifenis ``ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Auth::RegistrationsController#create`` This is full error. Its exposed.